# Is there an easy way to fake a Sitecore Device for testing?

Tags: sitecore

We have a custom device set-up in a Sitecore installation.  Is there an easy way to get my desktop to render that?

I'd imagine there should be a nice parameter sc_device= we can tag onto the url, but it doesn't seem so

Comment: Did you create new device under  /sitecore/Layout/Devices ? Did you also set query string field on the new device (something like ?d=m ) ? Did you publish devices,layouts, etc ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are doing your device detection, you can also emulate devices in Chrome: http://www.sitepoint.com/use-mobile-emulation-mode-chrome/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sc_device` is exactly what you need. Just make sure that you use device item id, not name, e.g.:

```
http://localhost?sc_device={46D2F427-4CE5-4E1F-BA10-EF3636F43534}
```

Answer (score 1):

sc_device is correct. Your problem must lie elsewhere; like suggested maybe your device has not been published etc.

Nice article documenting Sitecore Querystrings here: http://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2013/07/sitecore-query-strings-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you create new device under /sitecore/Layout/Devices ? Did you also set query string field on the new device (something like ?d=m ) ? Did you publish devices,layouts, etc ?